# Wrong numbers or errors when reading rows of numbers from a data file

Tags: java, file, project

I'm trying to read a data file and take the 3 rows of numbers and store them into an array. I'm so confused on how I should approach this. Im not even sure if my `while` loop is even correct. The format of the file is throwing me off. I create variables to hold the name, school, scores, and difficulty for the diver but when I put it in my `diveScore` method the numbers are wrong, or theres an error reading the file when i don't use the `Double.parseDouble()` way. The parameters for the method are the dive number (1 to 3), the array of 7 scores, and the difficulty of the dive (1 to 4). Do I also call the diveScore method 3 times for each dive? Each diver has 3 dives which is why there are 3 rows of numbers.

**Diver Class:**

```
    public class Diver {
    
    private String name;
    private String school;
    private double [] scoreArray = new double[3];
    private double totalScore;

    Diver() {
        
    }
    Diver(String name, String school) {
        this.name = name;
        this.school = school;
    }
    //loop through score array and calculate the total score for each dive attempt
    public double [] diveScore(int diveNum, double [] scores, double difficulty) {
        double min = min(scores);
        double max = max(scores);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            totalScore += scores[i];
        }
        totalScore -= max;
        totalScore -= min;
        totalScore *= difficulty;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
            scoreArray[i] = totalScore;
        }
        return scoreArray;
    }
    //finds smallest score in array of scores
    private double min(double [] scores) {
        java.util.Arrays.parallelSort(scores);
        
        double min = scores[0];
        return min;
    }
    //finds largest score in array of scores
    private double max(double [] scores) {
        java.util.Arrays.parallelSort(scores);
        
        double max = scores[scores.length - 1];
        return max;
    }
    //calculates total of the 3 dives
    public double totalScore() {
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
                totalScore += scoreArray[i];
        }
        return totalScore;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String str = name + ", " + school + ": " + totalScore + "\n" + "Dive 1: " + scoreArray[0] + "\n" + "Dive 2: " + scoreArray[1] + "\n" + "Dive 3: " + scoreArray[2] + "\n";
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Main File:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Diver [] divers = new Diver[25];
    int numDivers = readFile(divers);
    System.out.println(numDivers);
    
}
public static int readFile(Diver [] divers) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File f = new File("divers.dat");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(f);
    Diver d;
    
    int count = 1;
    int diveNum = 1;
    while (kb.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = kb.nextLine();
        String school = kb.nextLine();
        String s1 = kb.next();
        String s2 = kb.next();
        String s3 = kb.next();
        String s4 = kb.next();
        String s5 = kb.next();
        String s6 = kb.next();
        String s7 = kb.next();
        String diff = kb.next();
        
        
        double score1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        double score2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        double score3 = Double.parseDouble(s3);
        double score4 = Double.parseDouble(s4);
        double score5 = Double.parseDouble(s5);
        double score6 = Double.parseDouble(s6);
        double score7 = Double.parseDouble(s7);
        double difficulty = Double.parseDouble(diff);
        
        double [] scores = new double [7];
        scores[0] = score1;
        scores[1] = score2;
        scores[2] = score3;
        scores[3] = score4;
        scores[4] = score5;
        scores[5] = score6;
        scores[6] = score7;
            
        count++;
        diveNum++;
    }
    kb.close();
    return count;
}
public static void printDivers(Diver [] divers, int numDivers) {
    System.out.println("All Divers\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < divers.length; i++) {
        if (divers[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(divers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Data File:

```
Lucieta Spinelli
Bryn Mawr College
8 9 8 7 8 8 8 2.5
7 8 7 6 7 7 6 3.7
8 7 6 7 7 6 8 3.2
LiPing Sun
Rutgers University
6.5 5 9.5 7.5 8 8.5 7 2.3
7 9 7.5 9 8.5 6.5 8 2.6
6 4 5 9 7 8 6 3.0
Greg McEntire
University of Southern California
9 8 8.5 9.5 9 9.5 7 2.3
9 7 8 8 7.5 8.5 7.5 2.6
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 3.4
Shiva Vadaparthy
Northwestern University
9 8 9.5 9.5 7.5 8 8.5 3.0
8 9 8.5 7.5 9 8.5 8 3.6
7.5 9 8 7 8.5 8 7 4.1
Elizabeth Bennet
Oxford University
7 8 9 8 7 7 8 2.4
8 8 6 7 9 7 8 2.7
8 7 8 6 9 8 9 3.0
Sofia Berrios
Universidad Simon Bolivar
8.5 7.5 9.5 9 7 8.5 8 2.4
8 7 8 9 8 6 7 3.0
7 5.5 6.5 7 5 6.5 7 3.6
Amir Majid
Reed College
4 5 6 5 3 5 7 2.8
7 6 7 8 7 9 8 2.9
8 9 7 9 8.5 8 9 3.4
James Pajuio
University of Pennsylvania
8 7 8 9 8 6 7 2.8
7.5 9 8 7 8.5 8 7 3.0
7.5 9 8 7 8.5 8 7 4.3
Sharon Lewis
Howard University
8 9 9.5 9 8.5 8 9 2.7
4 5 5.5 7 6.5 4.5 5 3.2
8 7 8 9 8 8 7 4.0
Divya Patel
Temple University
7 9 7.5 9 8.5 6.5 8 2.1
8 7 8 6 9 8 9 2.3
3.5 5.5 4 5 3 4 4.5 4.3
Guo Zhang
Portland State University
5 6 5.5 7 6.5 7 5.5 6 3.0
8 7 8.5 9 7.5 8.5 8 3.2
9 8 9.5 8.5 9 8.5 9.5 4.1
Tomasz Wojaczyk
Tufts University
8 8 7 8 7 8 7 2.6
5 4 5 6 7 5 5 2.9
8 6 6 7 8 7 6 3.6
```

Comment: If you need the actually project question to clear my whole paragraph up then ill make a comment for that too. I know what I said is confusing. Im sorry.

Comment: Also, the output of this current code is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Rutgers"
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
 at Main.readFile(Main.java:34)
 at Main.main(Main.java:10)

Comment: 1) Write unit tests for each method, to verify that your code is doing what you think it should be doing.  It's a fantastic habit to be in, and can be jolly satisfying.  2) Run your code line by line in debugging mode so you can watch the variables change and understand what's going on.  3) Your array double[] scores in the readFile() method is created within the method and not returned from the method.  As far as the rest of your program is concerned, this array might as well not exist!  4) Feel free to ask for more specific help on any of these points :)

Comment: The information about that exception should go in your question. You can edit your question to add it instead of just having it in a comment where it can easily be overlooked. (Also, comments on SO aren't as permanent as questions and answers; they can be removed by moderators for various reasons.)

Comment: You could use a debugger. Or you could put a lot of print statements. I would suggest that you print out all the items that you've just read before you parse any of them. It will be enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here. The ones that are causing your exception are:

You read a number with the `next()` method of `Scanner`, which leaves the end-of-line character at the end of the line, and then you try to read the next name with the `nextLine()` method, which is going to return an empty string for the name since the scanner is looking at the end of the line.

This is compounded by the fact that the lines for the name and school are followed by three lines of eight numbers each, or twenty-four numbers total, but you only try to read eight numbers.

The result is that you get "Lucieta Spinelli" and "Bryn Mawr College" and then the numbers 8, 9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 2.5 for the first entry, and then the name "" and the school "7 8 7 6 7 7 6 3.7" and then the numbers 8, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 3.2 for the second entry, and finally you get the name "" and the school "LiPing Sun" and then the numbers "Rutgers" and "University" and...

Well, that's as far as you get, since "Rutgers" isn't a number and when you try to convert it into one with `parseDouble` your program crashes.

You also aren't using the `Diver` class at all; you never create a Diver. There's also no point in reading the numbers into `s1` and so on just to parse them and stick them in an array; you might as well just parse them into the array directly and leave `s1` out of it, but that's minor.

The call to `kb.close()` should be inside a `finally` block, or else you should use a [try-with-resources block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure the file gets closed.

I would strongly suggest reading Eric Lippert's excellent article, [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); with the skills it would provide you with, you would likely not have needed to ask this question at all.